# HTML5 Geolocation - getting longitude and latitude and save it in php variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, google-maps

I am making one project where I have to get longitude and latitude of user, to mark the place where the he is and so on. The problem is to save longitude and latitude in php variable, which at the end will be saved in MySQL database. So, does anyone know is that possible to achieve.

Comment: sure it can be achieved by sending the coordinates via `ajax` from js to php and save them to mysql or whatever. look for how to making an ajax call..

Comment: what have you tried sofar no code no fiddle how can we help you if you don't tell us

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549439/getting-database-values-in-javascript-variable-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

See example here http://html5demos.com/geo. Than change it:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
 error('not supported');
}

function successFunction(position) {
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var longi = position.coords.longitude;

   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: { latitude : lat, longitude : longi },
      url: //....
      //... passing on server
   });
}
```

Comment: This is not going to continuously store the lat lang