# how to get database value into javascript google map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

i know there is the same question like mine but i still don't understand...

i want to make a google map with value in my database
there are 3 value in my database: name, lat, and lon.

and i want to get this value and add this into my javascript.

here is my google map script (stil fresh from w3school) :

```
<script>

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51,508743,-0,12085);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

i have read this question :[Getting database values in Javascript variable dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549439/getting-database-values-in-javascript-variable-dynamically) .

but still dont understand how it works, what do i need to add and what do i need to change. please help

Comment: fetch the data from database and replace your value with variable as below

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat;?>,<?php echo $lang;?>);

Comment: what the... its THAT simple ??? wow, i dont understand why i take the long route... i always thought you need to put the recordset or table name before the variable... thanks a lot man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which language?

In PHP you have to just use your variables with db table column values in place of long and lat.

e.g.  and

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(,);

Let me know if you want the multiple maps with in the loop.

Vikash

Comment: i am using dreamweaver php for my web, so yeah i am using php languange... but i dont know what to add or what to add in the script php or javacript.

Comment: thanks man... i got it now, and if i can become greedy . i want to know how to use multiple map like you said.

Comment: [link](https://shellcreeper.com/multiple-location-google-map/)

Please read this tutorial. Very easy to implement.